# Compiling GRPC server/client

Tags: java, compilation, rpc, grpc

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to compile a GRPC Java server. I looked all over the grpc.io website and closest thing I found was this: http://www.grpc.io/docs/#quick-start , where I run 
`../gradlew -PskipCodegen=true installDist` to build, and 
`./build/install/grpc-examples/bin/hello-world-client` to run the client. This all works, but only for the hello-world tutorial. I have no idea how to do this for my own client/server. I'm able to generate the client/server protobufs using the .proto file. I looked in their readme and Java tutorial and couldn't find out how to compile the actual server (and client) after I write them
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/README.md
(can't link java tutorial because I dont have enough reputation). Unless there's documentation im missing, does anyone know how to compile a server and client that implements the GRPC classes generated from the .proto file? I did spend a fair amount of time searching. Any advice is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Also have a similar problem, ensure that:

1. You configured correctly the `protoc`, that will be [downloading the executable](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.0.0) and configure it as an environment variable of your OS.
2. The `build.gradle` file, make sure to include [protobuf-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin):

   ```
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'idea'
   apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

   ext.grpcVersion = '1.0.1'
   ext.protobufVersion = '3.0.2'

   buildscript {
   repositories { mavenCentral() }
   dependencies { 
   classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0' }
   }

   repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
   compile "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:${protobufVersion}"
   compile "io.grpc:grpc-all:${grpcVersion}"
   }

   protobuf {
   protoc { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobufVersion}"     }
   plugins { grpc { artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}" } }
   generateProtoTasks { ofSourceSet('main')*.plugins { grpc { } } }
   }

   idea {
   module {
       sourceDirs +=     file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java");
       sourceDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/grpc");
   }
   }
   ```
3. Your `proto` file:

   ```
   syntax = "proto3";
   package com.company.project;

   service CompanyService{
       rpc call(RequestMessage) returns (ResponseMessage) {}
   }
   ```
4. Run `gradle clean build`, and it should generate your service and client classes for `CompanyService`.

The `idea` plugin, is jut for telling IntelliJ to recognize the `src/main/proto` as a source set.

5. To actually execute the client and server, you will need to make the implementation, mentioned in the tutorial for gRpc, and then apply the `application` plugin, in order to generate correctly the executable `jar`

   ```
   //build.grdle code...
   apply plugin: 'application'
   mainClassName = 'com.company.project.MainClass'
   jar { manifest { attributes('Main-Class' : mainClassName) } }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but solved it using it in Gradle by adding the 'application' plugin. Before I was using the 'java' plugin and I could only generated a jar file. After switching to the 'application' plugin there is a gradle task similar to the gRPC example.

```
./gradlew installDist
```

And now to start your server you can run something similar to this:

```
./build/install/your-project/bin/your-server
```

To actually generate the Java classes off my .proto files I needed to run './gradle build' and also include the source generated using the sourceDir element you can see in the build.gradle below.

This is the full build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'idea'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.7.6'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.grpc:grpc-all:0.14.0'
}

mainClassName = "com.domain.service.YourMainClass"

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0-beta-2"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:0.14.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc");
        sourceDirs += file("${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/java");
    }
}
```

I am new to gRPC so any improvments to my Gradle file would be appericated.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered [on groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/grpc-io/Kwtdz_iYBUk/_7fhPWwvDAAJ) by 'Eric Anderson':

> The JAR only has your code in it. It sounds like you want to make a "fat" jar which includes all your dependencies. You can do something like this:
>
> ```
> jar {
>       from {
>           configurations.compile.collect {
>               it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Note that that isn't gRPC-specific; it's just working with Gradle. There may be alternatives, such as a quick Googling returned gradle-fatjar-plugin.

Comment: I've edited your answer to quote the answer on Google Groups that you've linked to. That way, your answer is protected against link-rot, and is not liable to be deleted as a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827).